# How to force white space in string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I create a function to check if string have a good French social number format

```
function isValidNoSecu(Tel) { return new RegExp(/[12]\s{1}\d\d\s{1}\d\d\s{1}\d\d\s{1}\d\d\d\s{1}\d\d\d\s{1}|\s{1}\d\d$/i).test(Tel); }
```

The string must have this form : X XX XX XX XXX XXX | XX
First X is 1 or 2 Nothing other
I need space (this is my biggest problem) I try \s or \s{1} or [ ] always accepting no space... and I want a space. In fact, the best response will be with just one space caracter not tab... then \s not good
Other X are digits : \d

I read lot of tutos, posts and try several tester but I don't find good regex
Thanks for your help

Comment: Use a space instead of `\s` because that could also match newlines and if you want to match the pipe itself, you have to escape it `\|` Using the Regex constructor you have to double escape the backslash.

Comment: `{1}` is useless

Comment: The problem is really with the alternating operator `|`, which must be escaped

Comment: Look at what your reg exp looks like visually https://regexper.com/#%2F%5B12%5D%5Cs%7B1%7D%5Cd%5Cd%5Cs%7B1%7D%5Cd%5Cd%5Cs%7B1%7D%5Cd%5Cd%5Cs%7B1%7D%5Cd%5Cd%5Cd%5Cs%7B1%7D%5Cd%5Cd%5Cd%5Cs%7B1%7D%7C%5Cs%7B1%7D%5Cd%5Cd%24%2Fi

Comment: Hi #The fourth bird if u put it in answer I put it in accepted response. Your the 1st with good answer

Comment: @YannickIngenierie That is kind of you, but there is already a good answer posted so no need to duplicate it. Glad it worked for you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a space character to indicate matching the  (space) character literally.

You can also use curly braces after a character to specify the number of matches required, e.g. `\d{2}` means match `\d` twice only.

And finally, you need to escape the pipe `|` character (using a backslash, like `\|`) because it is a special character, meaning `OR`.

Like this:

```js
const re = /[12] \d{2} \d{2} \d{2} \d{3} \d{3} \| \d{2}/

console.log(re.test("1 11 22 33 444 555 | 66"))
console.log(re.test("2 33 44 55 666 777 | 88"))
```